# How can I create a titlepage without a newpage in the scrartcl class

Tags: titles, koma-script, article

I would like to create my own `title` in the `scrartcl` class. Using the `titlepage` environment gives me a new page, but I would like to suppress this page break. How can I do this?

Edit:
In general a title is set by `\maketitle`. Now I would like to set my own title style with the titlepage environment. How do I get the same page layout than with `\maketitle`? Or should I set the title without the use of any special environment?

Comment: Why do you use the environment if you don't want the title on a page of its own?

Comment: How would you set your own title style? Simple write it down, without a special environment?

Comment: @Dirk: If you like to use the `titelpage` fields provided by KOMA-Script why not use this workaround. Normally I would be the same opinion as @ulrike-fischer but afak if you are using those fields you are able to reuse them later in the text.

Comment: @Rico The `titlepage` environment doesn't use or provide any special fields. It simply creates an empty page. If you don't want an empty page you don't gain anything by using it. Dirk: Yes: simply write down the title.  And if you don't feel comfortable with such a plain solution: Define a command `\mymaketitle` and use this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Oh sorry, I mixed it up with `\maketitle`, my bad!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. Sometimes one does not see the wood for the trees. I mixed your suggestions and use the fields from `\maketitle` in an extended way.
@Rico Your suggestion helped, but I missed some requirements, so it does not solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add this to your preamble:

```
\let\endtitlepage\relax
```

this does it for me.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I implied some requirements that I did not write down. I will edit my first post.